# WPF custom grid with property to set with databinding

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I am using WPF and I have a custom datagrid. What I would like to do is add a property (CustomGridCommands) to that grid which I can set in xaml from any view.

What I have at the moment is as follows (I have changed the code a bit to simplify it):

Custom grid C# code:

```
public class CustomWPFDataGrid : DataGrid, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CustomContextMenuCommandsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CustomContextMenuCommands", 
                                    typeof (ObservableCollection<WPFBaseCommand>),
                                    typeof (CustomWPFDataGrid));

    [Bindable(true)]
    public ObservableCollection<WPFBaseCommand> CustomContextMenuCommands
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<WPFBaseCommand>) GetValue(CustomContextMenuCommandsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CustomContextMenuCommandsProperty, value); }
    }
...
...
}
```

XAML code:

```
<common:CustomWPFDataGrid 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemList}"
        CustomContextMenuCommands="{Binding Path=CustomGridCommands, Mode=TwoWay}">
....
</common:CustomWPFDataGrid >
```

The object I have bound to the view that contains the grid is as follows:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<TestDisplayViewModel> ItemList { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<WPFBaseCommand> CustomGridCommands;

    public TestViewModel()
    {
    ... population of objects here
    }
```

When I run this, and check the value of the property (CustomContextMenuCommands) in the datagrid, it is always null.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

### EDIT

The setter of the "CustomContextMenuCommands" is never hit.

Comment: Well, CustomGridCommands in your ViewModel is private, View cannot use it.

Comment: Ah sorry that was a typo. I had hand typed it into my question. It was actually public. However...it was a public variable and not a public property. That fixed it. Seeing you sent me in the right direction...you want to post it up as the answer and I'll accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CustomGridCommands` in your ViewModel is a field, View cannot use it. If you make it a public property, then it will become accessible. More details on what can be used as binding source can be found on [MSDN - Binding Sources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms743643%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#binding_sources).

If using WPF 4.5, static properties can also be used for binding, as described in [release notes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613588%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#static_properties).